# Send additional data to form initialisation

Tags: django, django-views, django-forms, django-validation

So I'm creating a form object using request.POST data, but want to initialise additional fields using other values.
This is what i tried, it isn't working:

#forms.py

```
class InputForm3(forms.Form):
    url = forms.URLField(required=True)
    db = forms.CharField(required=False)
    wks = forms.CharField(required=True, initial="Sheet1")
    table = forms.CharField(required=False, initial="test_table")

def __init__(self, wks, *args, **kwargs):
        self.wks=wks
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.cleaned_data = None

def clean(self):
        self.cleaned_data = super().clean()
        print("FORM3 cleaned_data : ", self.cleaned_data)
```

#views.py

```
form3=InputForm3(wks="Sheet1", data= request.POST)
if form3.is_valid:
    #remaining code
```

#output

```
FORM3 cleaned_data :  {'url': 'https://randomurl.com', 'db': 'testdb', 'table': ''}
```

the fields 'url' and 'db' are present directly in request.POST, HOW DO I INITIALISE THE OTHER FIELDS PLEASE HELP!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure of the context of why you'd want to do that.

But maybe you can try copying the form's `data` after you initialized the form with the `request.POST` `data`. You'll have access to modify the copied `data`. For example:

If you're using a `function-based view`:

```
def view_name(request):
     form3 = InputForm3(request.POST)

     if request.method == "POST":
          form3 = InputForm3(data=request.POST) # removing wks from the parameter here...

          # assigning the copied collection of data to the form's data so we can modify it
          form3.data = form3.data.copy()
          form3.data['wks'] = 'Sheet1' # or whatever name you wish to name that wk

          if form3.is_valid():
               # remaining code
          ...
```

If you're using a `class-based view`:

```
def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
     form3 = InputForm3(data=request.POST)

     form3.data = form3.data.copy()
     form3.data['wks'] = 'Sheet1'

     if form3.is_valid():
          # remaining code
     ...
```

That worked for me.